# which directory should the download file be put

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

Since ios5, the file in the NSDocument would be upload to iCloud automatically, if the file in NSDocument is too large Apple would reject the app. 
I want to know what path should I store the downloaded file, and what path to store un-completed file (Would not be deleted when application terminate)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Caches directory is suitable for files that can be replaced if they were to disappear. In other words, if the file you download can simply be downloaded again if it were to be deleted, then the Caches directory is a good place.

If the downloaded file isn't replaceable and the downloaded file is something that the user initiates as data for the app, then the Documents directory is actually a good place and shouldn't cause rejection.

Comment: Yeah, there's some niggling small print, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: You could always store the file in the documents directory, but set the do not backup attribute for the folder you put it in. The file would not be deleted when a user upgrades his app also.